# Fast way to detct if variable is multiline or not in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

Looking for a quick way in BASH to test whether my variable is single or multiline? I thought the following would work but it always comes back as `no`

```
input='foo
bar'

regex="\n" ; [[ $regex =~ "${input}" ]] && { echo 'yes' ; } || { echo 'no' ; }
```

Comment: `\n|\r|\r\n|\n\r` the might be a carriage return in there too....

Comment: The *right*-hand side of `=~` is a regular expression not the left.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `wc -l` for the test: `[[ $(echo $input | wc -l) -ge 1 ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"`

Comment: @EtanReisner good point, missed that

Comment: @JNevill +1 for the idea of using `wc` i hadn't thought of that either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex as you can use glob pattern to check for this:

```
[[ $str == *$'\n'* ]] && echo "multiline" || echo "single line"
```

`$str == *$'\n'*` will return true if any newline is found in `$str`.

Comment: Awesome, plus one and waiting to accept. thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex like below,

```
$ regex="[\\r\\n]"
$ [[ "${input}" =~ $regex ]] && { echo 'yes' ; } || { echo 'no' ; }
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a regex. Just erase everything that is not a "new line", and count characters:

```sh
str=$'foo\nbar\nbaz'
```

Not calling any eternal program (pure bash):

```sh
b=${str//$'\n'};  echo $(( ${#str} - ${#b} ))
```

The number printed is the number of new lines.

An alternative solution is to cut the variable at the `\n`, and find if it got shorter:

```sh
b="${str%%$'\n'*}"; (( ${#b} < ${#str} )) &&  echo "Multiline"
```

Note that this will fail if the line end is `\c` (one CR, as in classic MAC).